# How to check which button was clicked using Netbeans GUI editor

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

Currently I am designing my GUI form and I am wondering about one thing.
Here is my GUI:
[image]

I want to add the same ActionPerformed method to all of these buttons, but in ActionListener only one parameter can be set (or I dont know how to change it), that is ActionEvent evt.

My question is : how to add another parameter to be sent to ActionPerformed, according to which button was clicked, and then lets say print in console text from button?

It is not possible to do it while just editing code (ActionListener) because NetBeans editor blocks such things.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems that you are confusing your program's event loop with the business logic itself -- there are virtually no circumstances that you would ever want to modify ActionPerformed. Why don't you explain in more detail what you're actually trying to do? Are you trying to get all buttons to execute the same action, regardless of the one you clicked? Take some time to read about the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Are you trying to get all buttons to execute the same action, regardless of the one you clicked?
Yes, thats exactly what I want to achieve. Editing code was one of my solutions but not the question itself ;)

Answer (score 0):

> and then lets say print in console text from button?

You write a generic listener. The `ActionEvent` contains the button that was clicked.

The basic logic would be:

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
        System.out.println( button.getText() );
    }
}

...

button1.addActionListener( al );
button2.addActionListener( al );
```